# Wordpress Editor without buttons

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

I'm trying to add Worpdpress editor on a modal page and in a different php file, but it doesn't show me the buttons, I put the screenshot

[image]

Also in the php file, First I hidden the editor to load the scripts.

```
<?php   
do_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts' );
?>
<?php
 echo '<!--';
 wp_editor( '', 'customEditor', array(
       'media_buttons' => false,
        'textarea_rows' => 10,
        'teeny' => true
    ));
 echo '-->';
```

Then in the modal window I call back to the editor via ajax:

```
wp_editor(' ', 'customEditor',$settings); 
\_WP_Editors::enqueue_scripts();
\_WP_Editors::editor_js();
```

Edit:
The problem is that it doesn't show me any errors in the console.

Comment: Have you checked the site with your browser's developer tools? Are there any issues in the markup or something logged to the browser console?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't show me any errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding the following script after making the Ajax call:

```
tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, 'customEditor');
tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, 'customEditor');
```